# What do you call the pages at the end of a book(children books) that you can "break down"

Tags: word-usage, translation

Im a spanish speaker I do not know how to properly call this kind of "pages".
 The pages and the end of a children books that are meant to play or have figures for children to cut. 
In spanish we call them "hojas desglosables"

Comment: We might refer to the paper or toys as as "cut-outs", but I can't think of any specific word for those pages.

Comment: BTW, in English, we ask "*What* do you call....?" *How* is not idiomatic there.

Answer (score 2):

An **Activity page** is often used to describe pages in a children's book that are more interactive than narrative.  Here is a great example of a book, [Fabulous Fables](https://books.google.com/books?id=7vYCgC-5ElAC&pg=PA13#v=onepage&q&f=false), with an activity page section at the end.

The term [activity book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Activity_book), would be a book containing mostly activity pages.

Comment: +1 Yes indeed; see e.g. **[here](https://books.google.com/books?id=7vYCgC-5ElAC&pg=PA13#v=onepage&q&f=false)**. (Feel free to add this link to your answer.)

Comment: Yes indeed this is an activity book, the whole book is full of interactive pages for the kid. E.g painting with colors, tempera, plasticine... But at the end there are figures that the child has to cut to paste at the active pages? I don't know if im making sense. My english is not that good.

Comment: @NuriaZavaleta  Is your question only asking about the specific pages that contain cut outs?